# substring in python 3 given line number and offset

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'm trying parsing an html page with the [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) library in python 3.
The function HTMLParser.[getpos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos)() return the line number and the offset of the last tag parsed.

For example I know that the "string" I want starts in line number 10 offset 5 and ends in line number 30 offset 10 how can I get the substring from line 10 offset 5 to line 30 offset 10 ?

Thanks.

```
html = 'this holds the entire html code'
MyParser.feed(html) #now the parser works its magic
start = (10,5) #this is returned from HTMLParser.getpos(), 10 is the line number and 5 is the offset of that line
end = (30,10) #same here
#I want to do something like this (I know this is invalid python code)
substring = html.substring(start,end) #return the html code as a string from line 10 offset 5 to line 30 offset 10
```

Better Explanation:

I'm trying to get a substring from a string.

I understand in python 3 it's called slice: string[a:b]
so if I wanted the substring 'jonny' form the string 'Hello jonny smith'
I would do this: `substring = 'Hello jonny smith'[6:11]`
The problem is that [HTMLParser.getpos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos) returns a tuple (line number, offset of that line) so I can't do: `substring = multy_line_string[line number:offset]`

Comment: You need to show us a bit more than this.

Comment: Did not understand problem you are trying to solve. Agree with Thorn, more details please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in HTML parsing try lxml --> http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed HTMLParser records the line and position in the line.

Here is the way to record the position in the stream:

```py
    def updatepos(self, i, j):
        self.rawpos = i
        return super().updatepos(i, j)
```

Now, assuming the string you are looking for stands inside `mytag`:

```py
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'mytag':
            self.mytag_pos = self.rawdata.index('>', self.rawpos) + 1

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'mytag':
            self.mytag_data = self.rawdata[self.mytag_pos:self.rawpos]
```