# Parsing HTML with entity ref

Tags: python, html, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse some HTML which has as an example

```
<solids>
&sub2;
</solids>
```

The html file is read in as a string. I need to insert the HTML from a file that sub2 defines into the appropriate part of the string before then processing the whole string as XML.

I have tried HTMLParser and using its handlers with

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
   def handle_entityref(self, name):
   # This gets called when the entity is referenced
   print "Entity reference : "+ name
   print "Current Section  : "+ self.get_starttag_text()
   print self.getpos()
```

But getpos returns a line number and offset rather than position in the string. ( The insertion can be at any point in the file )

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392343/substring-in-python-3-given-line-number-and-offset) and this suggest to use lxml. I have looked at lxml but cannot see how it would solve the problem. Its scanner does not seem to have an entity handler and seems to be xml rather than html

Comment: I don't under what "need to insert the HTML from a file that sub2 defines into the appropriate part of the string " means. Can you give an example and the desired output?

Comment: The file starts with
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE gdml [

<!ENTITY sub2 SYSTEM "sub2.xml">
]>
`
So sub2 refers to a file that should be included at the point between <sollid> and </solid>

Answer (score 0):

Okay found that lxml will handle the ENTITY references for me.

Just had to setup parser with the option resolve_entities=True

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=True)
root = etree.parse(filename, parser=parser)
```